# Join derived table with itself

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

In short words:

I have events table:
[tbl]

```
time | newState
1200 | 1
1300 | 2
1400 | 5
```

I need to transform this table into intervals table [intervals]:

```
t0   | t1   | state
1200 | 1300 | 1
1300 | 1400 | 2
```

RESTRICTION: SQL COMPACT EDITION

the query:

```
SELECT leftPart.time AS t0, min(rightPart.time) AS t1, leftPart.newState
FROM tbl AS leftPart 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl As rightPart
ON leftPart.time<rightPart.time
GROUP BY leftPart.Time,leftPart.newState
```

It works perfect when [tbl] is permanent table in database, but in my case [tbl] is derived from another select subquery! like this:

```
(SELECT time,newState
from ...) AS derivedTb
```

So, when i try something like this:

```
SELECT derivedTbl.time As t0,derivedTbl.state,min(rigthTblPart.time) FROM
(SELECT time,newState
from ...) AS derivedTbl
LEFT OUTER JOIN with derivedTbl AS rigthTblPart
ON derivedTbl.Time<rightTblPart.Time ...
```

It throws error: "derivedTbl does not exist"...

It seems that the derived table under it's alias is not visible to higher level query (thanks, google translator! ))...

Is there any way to store derived tables in query and using them in different parts of query? SQL CE doesn't support temporary tables, views and common table expressions...

**task details (if interesting):**
i have 2 tables of events:

```
[states1]
time | state1
1200 | 1
1300 | 2
1400 | 3

[states2]
time | state2
1200 | 0
1230 | 10
1330 | 20
1430 | 30
```

I need convert them in intervals table:

```
[intervals]
t0      t1      state1  state2
1200    1230    1   0
1230    1300    1   10
1300    1330    2   10
1330    1400    2   20
1400    1430    3   20
1430    NULL    3   30
```

stages of convertion:
1. overall timeline

```
(SELECT Time FROM States1 
UNION
SELECT Time FROM States2) AS timetbl
```

1. join states1 table
2. join states2 table

for this moment all goes well:

```
SELECT     states12tbl.time, states12tbl.state1, states2tbl.State AS state2
   FROM          (SELECT     states12tbl_1.time, states12tbl_1.state1, MAX(states2tbl.Time) AS states2time
       FROM          (SELECT     timetbl.time, states1tbl.State AS state1
           FROM          (SELECT     timetbl_1.Time AS time, MAX(States1tbl.Time) AS state1time
               FROM          (SELECT     Time
                   FROM          States1
                   UNION
                   SELECT     Time
                   FROM         States2) AS timetbl_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  States1 AS States1tbl ON States1tbl.Time <= timetbl_1.Time
               GROUP BY timetbl_1.Time) AS timetbl INNER JOIN
              States1 AS states1tbl ON timetbl.state1time = states1tbl.Time
```

1. join table with itself... and here is problem, i need to join code(3) with itself, because sql ce can't remember temp tables... If you have some better idea, please, share :)

Comment: Due to the limitation of SQL CE, you have to post the complete subquery, and we will see if we can do something. Otherwise, you have to write the subquery twice..

Comment: It seems that the only option is to write subquery twice, because there is no way to store temp tables in sql ce at all... Subquery is really difficult :) ...

Comment: Well, add the subquery code so we can try to help you, or delete your question because you won't have an answer since there is no answer !

Comment: subquery is any query that returns table [time,state]:
(SELECT time,newState FROM eventsTimeTbl InnerJoin statesTbl On eventsTimeTbl.Time=statesTbl.Time)
for example...

Answer (score 0):

Create a VIEW based on your first SELECT.

Comment: The engine wasn't specified initially.

Answer (score -1):

Onotole, I think that this WITH is making the trouble.

rewrite this query like

```
SELECT 
    derivedTbl.time As t0,
    derivedTbl.state,
    min(rigthTblPart.time) 
FROM
   (SELECT time,newState from ...) AS derivedTbl
   LEFT OUTER JOIN derivedTbl AS rigthTblPart
       ON derivedTbl.Time<rightTblPart.Time 
....
```

Comment: it trows an error: "derivedTbl does not exist" ... it can not remember subquery like temp table